# UPNP with a Blackberry Playbook

Tags: javascript, actionscript, air, blackberry-webworks, upnp

Trying to build an app the requires UPNP discovery. Is there any way to do this on the Blackberry Playbook? Scripts preferred are clientside HTML5/JS (ie Webworks) and Actionscript, although Java & Flash are supported as well.

Out of interest, what scripting languages do do UPNP discovery?

Comment: UPnP discovery is an application of network protocol, not of a "language". If a language (or rather APIs usable by that language) can do multicast HTTP over UDP, then it can do UPnP discovery. But to actually "do" it, you must write a nontrivial code (or use 3rd party). The only language(s) which come with UPnP out of the box is .NET family on Windows XP and newer.

Answer (score 1):

UPnP discovery relies on multicast UDP which isn't available through JavaScript.  I don't know of any ActionScript UPnP stack.

You're best bet would be to use a Java stack such as [ohNet](http://wiki.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet) or [Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling). Both of these are used by a variety of products and actively supported. For ohNet, discovery is handled by the CpDeviceListUpnpXxx classes; I'm not sure where you'd get started with Cling but it does have an active community if you need to ask questions.

[Disclaimer: I contribute to ohNet]

Comment: Even if any ActionScript stack existed, it seems that it won't work on [Playbook as Mobile device](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html) :-(

Comment: You could possibly create a Native webworks extension using C++ and use an existing open source upnp library library that supports QNX compilation. Going the AIR Route there is now an open source udp library at https://github.com/wouterverweirder/AIR-Mobile-UDP-Extension , which could allow you to to roll your own upnp library.

Comment: @techsaint Does Playbook support native code?  I thought Blackberry required that all app code was Java.

Comment: @simonc Yes, the playbook supports native code. Its the first major  blackberry device to do so. Going forward, BB10 and Playbook Devices all support the Blackberry NDK https://developer.blackberry.com/platforms/ndk